# TWRP stuck on splash screen, odin not recognizing phone

Tags: samsung, twrp, rom, odin

I have a Galaxy S5 (T-Mobile).

I recently booted into TWRP (flashed with odin,) and attempted to flash Resurrection Remix with NikGapps using an SD card. Upon reboot RR was stuck on the loading screen, and on reboot it tried to boot to TWRP but that got stuck on the splash screen too.

I tried to reflash with odin, but even in Download Mode the phone is not recognized by odin.

I've tried:

1. Countless reboots
2. Unplugging and replugging, trying different cables
3. Trying to get Fastboot to work (Unsuccessful)
4. Letting TWRP load for an hour (Unsuccessful)

Extra info: Every reboot redirects to the broken TWRP install, and Download Mode is still accessible from the phone.

If someone could help me, that would be nice because I'm scared this phone might be bricked.

Comment: Considering the age of your phone (about 7-8 years) a hardware defect is a likely cause for the problems: the soldering points of the USB-socket where it is connected to the mainboard can break when the USB plug is inserted too often with a high pressure or the plug was moved while inserted (prying effect).

Comment: broken twrp might still provide adb shell for emergency